# Correctly inserting nodes into a BST in C++

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I'm working on a BST to add floats from a file. As the code is written, it adds a new root each time because the root is not added and updated correctly. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Here's my create and add functions:

```
void BST::create() {
    string filename;
    ifstream file;
    float value;
    cout << "Enter the file name: ";
    if (getline(cin,filename)) {
        filename.insert(0, "C:/Temp/");
        file.open(("C:/Temp/%s",filename).c_str());
        if (!file) {
            cout << "Error opening file. Make sure it's located in c:/Temp and try again." << endl;
        }
        else if (file) {
            if (file >> value) {
                while(file >> value) {
                    addNode(this->root, value);
                }
                file.close();
            }
            else {cout << "No floats found." << endl;}
        }
    } else { cout << "Error. Please try again." << endl; }
}

void BST::addNode(Node *root, float val) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        root = new Node;
        root->key = val;
        root->leftChild = NULL;
        root->rightChild = NULL;
        cout << "added root" << endl;
        cout << "value is " << root->key << endl << endl;
    } 
    else {
        cout << "root value is " << root->key << endl;
        if (val < root->key) {
            if (root->leftChild == NULL) {
                cout << "adding left child " << val << endl;
                Node *tmp = new Node;
                tmp->key = val;
                tmp->parent = root;
                root->leftChild = tmp;
            } else {
                addNode(root->leftChild, val);
            }
        } 
        else {
            if (root->rightChild == NULL) {
                cout << "adding right child " << val << endl;
                Node *tmp = new Node;
                tmp->key = val;
                tmp->parent = root;
                root->rightChild = tmp;
            } 
            else {
                addNode(root->rightChild, val);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my constructor:

```
class BST 
{private:
    Node *root;
    void addNode(Node *root, float val);

 public:
  BST()     // a constructor
  {root = NULL;}

  ~BST();   // a destructor that frees all dynamically allocated spaces for the BST

  void display();
  void create();

};
```

(I know I'm not consistently curly-bracing. Sorry.)

Comment: aj has an answer that deserves attention. unrelated: a non-recursive (or recursive) insertion in a BST gets *significantly* simpler if you're willing to step one pace out of the box and utilize a pointer-to-pointer rather than a raft of temporaries. So yes, I would use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naming conventions will save your life! It seems you have shot yourself in the foot by making root both a member and a parameter.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. So should I just use a different variable name in the parameters of addNode?

Comment: +1 Or get used to `this->root` when you need the member. (which I personally detest, and flog engineers that do this)

Comment: Also don't be afraid to use the full word for variables. I will often use 4 words in a variable at word just so the next guy knows what's going on.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain what you mean? (regarding making the member mRoot, would that just be changing the variable name in the constructor?)

Comment: value should be spelled out in your addNode function. I was making my point by saying that others will always see your code some day. Code spends 90% of it's life being read vs 10% being written. Even if you are the only person working on it. So you could call "ifstream file" "ifstream fileFullOfFloats"

Comment: I'd call the parameter `subtree_root` or some other more precise description of what it represents. It's definitely not the same as the `root` member, obviously. Hungerian doesn't really help here, since it doesn't make it any clearer what the difference between the two variables is

Comment: I understand what you mean about variable naming. This is just for an assignment so I didn't feel compelled to be pedantic. My question was about 'making the member mRoot'. Could you explain that with a little more depth? I appreciate your help, I feel like you have the answer, I just don't know what to do with it.

Comment: In your addNode, you are always asking if the parameter root is null or not. So the first time it is, so the node gets added, but you never set this->root to root, so this->root is always null. I didn't mean to be indirect. I just wanted you to make the styling change so that you would catch your mistake for yourself so you would have more of an opportunity to learn, given this is a school assignment.

Comment: @prichey Though I am hard-pressed to say it simpler, perhaps I can say it differently. Your choice of member function parameter names in conjunction with member variable names is causing an unintended side effect that *hides* the member variable. Qualifying using `this->member` can patch up your member function without changing *either* the parameter or member variable names. But this makes the code somewhat difficult to follow and prone to bugs (like when you neglect to do so as you have here). A naming convention that consistently distinguishes your members from parameters is advised.

Comment: I figured it out. Once I renamed the parameter in addNode, I still had to initialize the new node with null pointers to children, which I thought I put in the constructor but I did not. Thanks everybody.

Comment: It is always a good idea to set all pointers to null by default in your ctor. It is especially important to set them to null after you have deleted the memory it points to; preventing dangling pointers. Also, if you have a func(int value); and func(int* value) the compiler will use func(int value) when you pass it null. I try to use the nullptr keyword if I can. nullptr is of type void* for this type of disambiguation. Good job tracking down that bug!